# Is it legal to combine JS and PHP ... Is that PHS or JHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Here I have an example... It works fine, but is it legal?

```js
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hide_3sec').fadeOut('fast');
```

```php
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET["msg"])){
        ?>
```

```js
                window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/admin/" + "?tab=accounts");
```

```php
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

```js
    }, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>
```

Comment: Well it's not illegal in the sense you will go to jail for it. It's a valid approach as long as that is written in a php file (otherwise the php wouldnt be parsed/executed and mess up the js). Wither or not it is the best approach is up to one's own opinions

Comment: No. You will be arrested for your transgression.

Comment: It's not my style, but it is perfectly legal... You are just dynamicalley generating your script tag content on the server.. nothing wrong with that in itself

Comment: Just keep in mind that PHP and JS execute at different times. PHP on the server, JS in the browser. Your code looks fine but lots of people make that mistake.

Comment: Definitely legal but not good practice.

Comment: You actually didn't combine PHP and JS. The PHP code runs on the server and generates whatever content the developer wants (usually HTML), the JavaScript runs in the browser, long after the PHP code completed its job. Many times, especially the beginners combine JavaScript with HTML and PHP to produce an unmaintainable mess. Use a template system to separate PHP and the content it generates. Store the JavaScript into `.js` files and reduce the inline JavaScript in the HTML to the minimum needed to configure the behaviour of the linked scripts.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's actually a quite common practice in order to pass server variables into the UI. Is it the best practice? I'm not qualified enough to answer that.

Example:

```
<script>
pageNumber = <?php echo $PAGE_NUM ?>
</script>
```

In your case, you have an entire if statement print out. It would be simpler to make the if statement always print out, but the boolean that's checked be printed by PHP.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hide_3sec').fadeOut('fast');
        if(<?php echo var_export(isset($_GET["msg"])); ?>){
            window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/admin/" + "?tab=accounts");
        }
    }, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>
```

Comment: Generating JavaScript code using the values received in the request is a terrible idea. The code posted in the question is, at least, safe.

Comment: Yes, if you use values received in the request, you need to sanitize the input to prevent XSS and similar attack vectors.